# Open only files with *.bin

Tags: vb.net

It is possible to add open only files with *.bin extension in openfile dialog ?
Here is my code. Maybe somebody can fix it.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim fullFile() As Byte
        If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            fullFile = File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)
            TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H1E).ToString("X2") & " ")
            TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H1F).ToString("X2"))
        End If
```

If file have another extension msg,box : Wrong file

Comment: That's not the Java I know...

Comment: Definitely not Java. @ymurok is this VB?

Comment: Ye it is VB, but I can't add my tags.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Filter` property: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    OFD.Filter = "BIN Files (*.bin)|*.bin"
    Dim fullFile() As Byte
    If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fullFile = File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)
        TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H1E).ToString("X2") & " ")
        TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H1F).ToString("X2"))
    End If
End Sub
```

The pipe `|` character is used in the filter string to separate it into chunks: the first is what the user sees in the dropdown, and the second is the actual filter that is run on the files. You can have multiple filters available, too. Here's another example of a filter string: `Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*`

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually restrict the user from choosing other file extensions, per se: the user can always type another filter into the box (like "*.*") to override what's selected in the File Types dropdown. If you want a MessageBox error (as you mentioned), I'd suggest a check before `File.ReadAllBytes` that examines the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `javax.swing.JFileChooser`.

Use this:

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Binary Files", "bin");
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```